# Unity formatting multiple numbers

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I'm a complete newb to unity and c# and I'm trying to make my first mobile incremental game. I know how to format a variable from (e.g.) 1000 >>> 1k however I have several variables that can go up to decillion+ so I imagine having to check every variable's value seperately up to decillion+ will be quite inefficient. Being a newb I'm not sure how to go about it, maybe a for loop or something?

EDIT: I'm checking if x is greater than a certain value. For example if it's greater than 1,000, display 1k. If it's greater than 1,000,000, display 1m...etc etc

This is my current code for checking if x is greater than 1000 however I don't think copy pasting this against other values would be very efficient;

if (totalCash > 1000)

```
    {
        totalCashk = totalCash / 1000;
        totalCashTxt.text = "$" + totalCashk.ToString("F1") + "k";
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're checking the variables against, for what purpose - or what you've tried.  Have a look at the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and edit your question.

Comment: I'm checking if they're greater than a value. For example if it's greater than 1,000, display 1k. If it's greater than 1,000,000, display 1m...etc etc

Comment: Ok, with you.  You should update your question with that, and whatever code you've tried to do it.

Comment: Edit is complete

Comment: By the way, if you want numbers that will exceed the 32 or 64 bit integer cap (9,223,372,036,854,775,807 or 9 pentillion), [Big Integer](https://numerics.codeplex.com/) resources are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I agree that copying code is not efficient. That's why people invented *functions*! 
How about simply wrapping your formatting into function, eg. named `prettyCurrency`?

So you can simply write:

```
totalCashTxt.text = prettyCurrency(totalCashk);
```

Also, instead of writing ton of ifs you can handle this case with logarithm with base of 10 to determine number of digits. Example in pure C# below:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    // Very simple example, gonna throw exception for numbers bigger than 10^12
    static readonly string[] suffixes = {"", "k", "M", "G"};
    static string prettyCurrency(long cash, string prefix="$")
    {
        int k;
        if(cash == 0)
            k = 0;    // log10 of 0 is not valid
        else
            k = (int)(Math.Log10(cash) / 3); // get number of digits and divide by 3
        var dividor = Math.Pow(10,k*3);  // actual number we print
        var text = prefix + (cash/dividor).ToString("F1") + suffixes[k];
        return text;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prettyCurrency(0));
        Console.WriteLine(prettyCurrency(333));
        Console.WriteLine(prettyCurrency(3145));
        Console.WriteLine(prettyCurrency(314512455));
        Console.WriteLine(prettyCurrency(31451242545));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
$0.0
$333.0
$3.1k
$314.5M
$31.5G
```

Also, you might think about introducing a new type, which implements this function as its `ToString()` overload.

EDIT:
I forgot about 0 in input, now it is fixed. And indeed, as @Draco18s said in his comment nor `int` nor `long` will handle really big numbers, so you can either use external library like `BigInteger` or switch to `double` which will lose his precision when numbers becomes bigger and bigger. (e.g. 1000000000000000.0 + 1 might be equal to 1000000000000000.0). If you choose the latter you should change my function to handle numbers in range (0.0,1.0), for which log10 is negative.

Comment: With a few tweaks I managed to get it working, thank you SO MUCH!